# Is it possible to calculate the moment of inertia of a sphere by taking the element as surface area $* dr$ ( change in radius)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Usually the proof for moment of inertia of a sphere involves taking the element to be a horizontal circular slabs and then integrating it.

I want to use another method to arrive at the same conclusion.

So my idea is, can we consider splitting the circle into small segments of surface area and thinckness?

Something like a structure of an onion.

If so, can you explain how?

If not, can you give the reason why isn't this possible?

Comment: Horizontal spherical slab? Do you mean horizontal circular disc?

Comment: As in spherical shells? Only if you take care to properly set up $dr$ so that it refers to the perpendicular distance from the axis of rotation.

Comment: Yes, its meant to be circular disks.

Comment: "Yes, its meant to be circular disks.". But then how is it "like a structure of an onion" at the same time?

Comment: @John According to standard proof done in textbooks, it is by circular method.

I want to focus on the spherical shell method.

Comment: I can post a proof using cylindrical shells if you like.  That's pretty straight forward because all the mass in the cylindrical shell has the same radius.  Trying with spherical shells would be a mess unless you just start with $I= 2/3 MR^2$ for a spherical shell ;)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method uses the symmetries of the sphere.

As $ J_{OX}=J_{Oy}=J_{Oz}=J$

we can say that :$$ 3J=\rho \int _{V}(x^{2}+y^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V+\rho \int _{V}(z^{2}+y^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V+\rho \int _{V}(x^{2}+z^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V$$ $$=\rho \int _{V}2(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V=2\rho \int _{V}(r^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V$$
where $r$ is the distance from point $M$ to the origin.
so :$$ 3J=2\rho \int _{V}(r^{2})\,\mathrm {d} V$$
$$ 3J=2\rho \int _{r}r^{2}\ (\int _{S}\,\mathrm {d} S)\mathrm {d} r=2\rho \int _{r}r^{2}\ \, S\;\mathrm {d} r$$
$$ 3J=2\times 4\pi \rho \int _{r}r^{4}\mathrm {d} r$$
$$ 3J=2\times 4\pi \rho {\frac {R^{5}}{5}}$$
with $$ \rho ={\frac {m}{{\frac {4}{3}}\pi \ R^{3}}}$$ $$ 3J=3{\frac {2mR^{2}}{5}}$$
so: $$ J={\frac {2mR^{2}}{5}}$$